# Why does Windows DIR command produce ??? characters instead of Russian alphabet?

Tags: windows-10, encoding, dir

On a Windows 10 box, via command line, I run this command:
**C:\Users\idiot\Music>dir /a:d /s /b >> tom-music-2016-july.txt**

The purpose is to list all directories. But I notice that directories with non-Roman letters in the name will print ????? instead of the Russian or Chinese characters.  Why?

Initially I thought that the problem was with system fonts. (I don't have a Russian language pack installed). But I can rename files to Russian file names in Win Explorer.  Importantly, when I run the DIR command in the window (without piping it to an output file), I **can clearly see Russian characters**.

That implies to me that the problem is either with the command which pipes something to a file or the Windows text editor which is trying to read the output.

I tried to open the file in 2 separate text editors and even in a web browser, but I see question mark characters regardless.

Can anybody suggest a cause of this problem and a possible solution?

Am I correct in assuming that I will not need to do any processing on the files or directories themselves? Thanks.

**Postscript:** I've particularly puzzled about why the Russian characters render fine in the console window but when it's piped to a file, I see the question marks.

Comment: see here for a deep explaination of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using#17177904

Comment: Use an editor which supports the appropriate character set, for example notepad++

Comment: I've tried to open in sublime editor, notepad++ and notetab light. Same result. Frank Thomas, as interesting as that question and explanation is, I don't think it explains why it renders fine inside the Windows console but not in the file that the text is outputted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing secret: encoding of a file created using `>` redirection follows current active code page of `cmd`. The `?` (a question mark) is simply a substitute (replacement marker) if a character does not exist in such a code page.

**Solution: use `UTF-8` (code page 65001)** as `chcp 65001`

The following example illustrates (*and perhaps proves*) it quite well:

```
d:\bat\UnASCII Names> chcp 1250
Active code page: 1250

d:\bat\UnASCII Names> dir /b /AD >dir1250.txt

d:\bat\UnASCII Names> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

d:\bat\UnASCII Names> dir /b /AD >dir65001.txt
```

The `dir1250.txt` and `dir65001.txt` files opened in Notepad++:

[image: redirection and encoding]

Please note that *so-called **`ANSI`*** is code page 1250 (Central European) in my locale while yours might be e.g. 1252 (US & Western Eu)…